# How to use homebrew to install java8 on MAC?

Tags: installation, homebrew

I'm trying to use `homebrew` to install java8 (I currently have java9) on my Mac.

I've tried using

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

but it appears that `java8` is no longer in that directory. Does anyone know what the path to java8 is?